# How to get fields in page layout

Tags: api, salesforce

Using the REST API in Salesforce, I want to get a list of the fields in a page layout.
Does anyone have any idea how I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this from the REST API, you can get it from the [describeLayout](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_describelayout.htm) call in the SOAP API.

Comment: thanks, initially I had a large sObject that the user selected the field from to create the layout. But I realised it was would be far simplier to create separate objects for each layout and let them add fields to that object as required. Then I used the REST API /vXX.X/sobjects/SObject/describe/ to get the list of the fields.

Comment: It is now possible to do this. See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/ for details

Answer (score 5):

As of API version 28.0 (Summer '13), you can [get the page layouts](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_sobject_layouts.htm) using `/sobjects/<object>/describe/layouts/<recordtypeid>`, e.g.
`/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/Account/describe/layouts/012A00000004vpXIAQ`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the REST API can accomplish this, however you could use the Salesforce [metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_layouts.htm) to do it.

Comment: Note that the `Modify All Data` permission is required to use the SOAP Metadata API (and that the REST Metadata API Pilot has been cancelled).

Answer (score 0):

You can do with rest api by calling object request.

```
curl https://***yourInstance***.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/Global/describe/layouts/ -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```