# get all RecordType fields from salesforce using REST API in PHP

Tags: php, salesforce, recordtype

I have used the below API for get all Case fields.

`/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/Case/describe/`

Here I got the `RecordType` option. I am able to get the `RecordType` information but I am not able to get the all fields in the particular `RecordType`. Could you please help me to get list of fields alone using `REST API` in PHP.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SOAP API, it's called [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describelayout.htm).

You also might have some luck with the new [Lightning/UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightningapi.meta/lightningapi/lightning_api_get_started.htm), which is REST. However, it's still in developer preview, so you'd need to contact Salesforce to get it enabled.

Also, have a look or submit the question to [Salesforce's StackExchange page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256190/how-to-get-fields-in-page-layout)